# A CSS Framework which is essentially a mobile-only (unresponsive) version of Bootstrap?

Tags: framework, css, bootstrap

I have a requirement to build a web application which

- will only run on mobile devices, specifically one model of mobile phone
- if someone opens it on a tablet or desktop browser, it should still look identical to the way it looks on mobile
- must be as lightweight (minimized css download) as possible
- should look (on mobile) as if it was built on bootstrap (with the default styles)
- mark-up (classes, grid system) should look undistinguishable to Bootstrap  developers
- should be easy to extend to tablet and desktop viewports later

I thought to myself: I could just go download Bootstrap and then strip it off all @media queries, leaving support for only the mobile ( "xs-" classes ) sized viewport.

And THEN, I thought: I don't want to maintain a fork of Bootstrap. Surely someone must already have thought of this, and maintains a public fork of Bootstrap 4 that's been stripped down for mobile-only?

I tried Googling and found only some unrelated stuff.

Does such a framework exist?

Comment: Can you please specify your 'phone's screen size? Without that, we can't help.

Comment: Seriously? Ok assume it’s an iPhone 6-7-8, non-plus.

Comment: Seriously? Absolutely, how could it not be? You want support for only one screen size - don't you think you ought to tell us what it is? What if I find something that supports only one screen size, but not the one that you want?

Comment: I would like to know if there exists a css framework that works in one mobile phone size but not another mobile phone size. I could probably shrink/stretch the content container and use it anyway.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just thinking of "phablets". Screen sizes can vary from about 4" to 10 or more, and I am not sure if bootstrap views them all the same.

Comment: Bootstrap’s first breakpoint is at 768px. But that doesn’t specifically matter. The fact that it has any media query at all is the problem (makes the css bloated with classes that will never be used).

Comment: Almost by definition, any framework that is free of media queries is going to be agnostic of precise screen size.

Comment: I'm using bs3.3.6 (because I must) and have removed all the media queries using postcss and a plugin but does not seem to be enough